# Какую библиотеку посоветуете для Android для 3D графика?

Tags: android, 3d, поиск-библиотек, графики

Я получаю данные пошагово, для каждого шага строится свой отдельный график, с этим все чудесно и все работает. Однако в конце эти все графики нужно объединить в один трёхмерный, какую библиотеку посоветуете и если кто-то сталкивался как лучше реализовать?

Comment: а как Вы сейчас строите отдельные графики?

Comment: с помощью библиотеки MPAndroidChart

Comment: В OpenGL ES сделайте (подойдет даже 1.0), зачем вам сторонние библиотеки?

Comment: попробую, спасибо, я первый раз встретился с OpenGL ES, не могли бы вы посоветовать какие-то видеоуроки или статьи по OpenGL ES пожалуйста?